# Convert bitmap to threshold (pure black and white)

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

I have tried this code for converting a bitmap to pure black and white - not greyScale, but this gives me a pure black image.

```
public Bitmap blackwhite(Bitmap source)  
    {
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(source.Width,source.Height);  
    for(int y=0;y<bm.Height;y++)   
    { 
    for(int x=0;x<bm.Width;x++) 
    {
    if (source.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness() > 0.5f) 
    {
    source.SetPixel(x,y,Color.White); 
    } 
    else  
    {
    source.SetPixel(x,y,Color.Black);  
    } 
    } 
    } 
    return bm; 
    }
```

What can cause such a problem? Is there any alternate method to this?

Comment: You're setting the pixel in the `source`, not in `bm`. I voted to close because it probably wouldn't help anyone else, it's a simple typo. Good luck!

Comment: Even after rectifying the typo the results are the same. I get a pitch black image after conversion.

Comment: Have you tried a lower brightness threshold like `> 0.1f`?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is way too late but I just figured it out and hope it helps other people having this problem.

I get the average brightness of the picture and use that as the threshold for setting pixels to black or white. It isn't 100% accurate and definitely isn't optimized for time complexity but it gets the job done.

```
public static void GetBitmap(string file)
        {
            using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(file, true))
            {    
                // Variable for image brightness
                double avgBright = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
                    {
                        // Get the brightness of this pixel
                        avgBright += img.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
                    }
                }

                // Get the average brightness and limit it's min / max
                avgBright = avgBright / (img.Width * img.Height);
                avgBright = avgBright < .3 ? .3 : avgBright;
                avgBright = avgBright > .7 ? .7 : avgBright;

                // Convert image to black and white based on average brightness
                for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
                    {
                        // Set this pixel to black or white based on threshold
                        if (img.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness() > avgBright) img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                        else img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    }
                }

                // Image is now in black and white
            }
```